# Boost awk performance using GNU parallel

Tags: awk, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have some subdirectories containing `.csv.gz` files. Using `awk`, I could manage to filter the files based on the values in column 1 and column 2 and dump the result in a single `.csv.gz` file.

```
 pigz -rdc /path/to/dir/ | awk -F, '{ if(($1>100) && ($2>100)) {print} }' | pigz > output.csv.gz
```

Thanks to `pigz`, the front and end of the bash pipe benefit from parallel processing. I'm wondering how can I use GNU **parallel** tool for executing `awk` jobs in parallel.

Comment: I can't help with your actual question but FYI `awk -F, '{ if(($1>100) && ($2>100)) {print} }'` can/should be written as just `awk -F, '($1>100) && ($2>100)'`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. It's more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doit() {
  pigz -dc "$1" | awk -F, '{ if(($1>100) && ($2>100)) {print} }'
}
export -f doit

find /path/to/dir -name '*.gz' | parallel doit | pigz > output.csv.gz
```

Comment: Thanks. It gives more than 3x speed-up on an 8 core machine.