# Passing Arguments to GNU parallel

Tags: bash, awk, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to use `awk` and GNU `parallel` to filter the files based on the values in column 1 and column 2 and dump the result in a single .csv.gz file. Thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67446989/boost-awk-performance-using-gnu-parallel), I could manage to write `myscript.sh` to do the job in parallel.

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
    pigz -dc $1 | awk -F, '$1>0.5 && $2<1.5'
}
export -f doit


find $1 -name '*.csv.gz' | parallel doit | pigz > output.csv.gz
```

and then run the script in the terminal.

```
./myscript.sh /path/to/files
```

I'm wondering how I can pass 0.5 and 1.5 as arguments of `myscript.sh`?

```
./myscript.sh /path/to/files 0.5 1.5
```

Comment: what's the current bottleneck that u need `parallel` for - the `gz` part of the `awk` part

Comment: The `gz` part is parallelized with `pigz` which is a parallel implementation of `gzip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
    # $1 $2 $3 are arguments to doit
    # '$1' and '$2' are variables in awk
    pigz -dc $1 | awk -F, '$1>'$2' && $2<'$3
}
export -f doit


find $1 -name '*.csv.gz' | parallel doit {} $2 $3 | pigz > output.csv.gz
```

Call as:

```
paste <(seq 10 | shuf) <(seq 10 | shuf) | gzip > h.csv.gz
./myscript.sh . 5 6
zcat output.csv.gz
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Seems a quotation mark is missing in the awk script. I fixed it but still, it doesn't work as it mixes up arguments.

Comment: @kiasari Fixed. (missed {})

Comment: Thanks. Perfectly worked.  I expected `'$1>'$2' && $2<'$3''` in awk script but how `'$1>'$2' && $2<'$3` works?

Answer (score 1):

This is may be an easier, or more explicit, way of passing variables and parameters around:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$1"
# Pick up second and third parameters, defaulting to 0.5 and 1.5 if unspecified
a=${2:-0.5}
b=${3:-1.5}

doit() {
    file=$1
    a=$2
    b=$3
    echo "File: $file, a=$a, b=$b"
    cat "$1" | awk -F, -v a="$a" -v b="$b" '$1>a && $2<b'
}
export -f doit

find "$dir" -name '*.tst' | parallel doit {} "$a" "$b"
```

Comment: Remember to quote your shell variables.