# Bash function skips pv (pipe viewer)

Tags: bash, pipe, gnu-parallel

Thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67446989/boost-awk-performance-using-gnu-parallel), I could manage to write `myscript.sh` to filter files based on the values in column 1 and column 2 in parallel.

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
    pigz -dc $1 | awk -F, '$1>0.5 && $2<1.5'
}
export -f doit


find $1 -name '*.csv.gz' | parallel doit | pigz > output.csv.gz
```

and then run it in the terminal.

```
./myscript.sh /path/to/files
```

However, `pv` (pipe viewer) command in the following script doesn't show the progress of data sent via the pipe.

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
    pv $1 | pigz -dc | awk -F, '$1>0.5 && $2<1.5'
}
export -f doit


find $1 -name '*.csv.gz' | parallel doit | pigz > output.csv.gz
```

I'm wondering how can I show the pipeline progress (not job progress with `parallel --progress`) using `pv`?